# Html.Action - Get versus Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, controller-action

I do this very often:

```
<div id='Product'>
@Html.Action("Create", "Product")
</div>
```

it's convenient because I can delegate the painting of a product creation form to another controller action for embedding in places.  However, I'm having issues in that the method will sometimes (I haven't figured out under what conditions) call the [HttpPost] of my controller action, which of course fails.

Is there a way to force @Html.Action() to call the GET version?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The way `Html.Action` works is that if the current request for the page is a post method then it will search for the method with the name `HttpPost`.

So what's happening is that you're POSTing the current page and the action likewise assumes all actions that should execute must be a POST too.

There's no way I know of to force it to switch to a different method like that.

Comment: yes, I did figure that out.  that is a terrible assumption on their part.  What I ended up doing is renaming the actions so that there's no ambiguity

Comment: That's probably the best solution. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the `AcceptVerbs` attribute to your action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get|HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //Your code
}
```

This will work for both GET and POST requests.

Comment: hmm... yes but that would force me to code both behaviours into the same method... which means I would need a way to tell within the method whether a Post or Get was performed... how would this be done?

Answer (score -1):

I also got into a similar problem and there indeed is a solution.
Just Check whether Request is get or POST in View using IsPost Property and VOILA....

```
@if(!IsPost)    
{    
    HTML.Action("ActionName")    
}
```

Regards to whoever got in similar problem...

Answer (score -2):

I just encountered this issue, which was hard to identify. I ended up using Html.RenderPartial instead, like this:

```
<div id='Product'>
@{Html.RenderPartial("_CreatePartial", new Product());}
</div>
```