# Is asp mvc 5 Html Action method Post or Get request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

What method the Html.Action use for rendering a partial views ?

Example 1 (with parameters):

```
@Html.Action("_PartialGetMemo", "Memos", new { id = 0 })
```

Example 2 (without parameters):

```
@Html.Action("_PartialGetMemo", "Memos")
```

Can somone explain how this works please ?

Comment: If the current request is a GET, then it will be a GET. If the current request is a POST, then it will look for a POST method first (and use that if it exists), then for a GET method

Comment: Related: [Html.Action - Get versus Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6554960/1220550)

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone
So there is no way to force it to use a specific method..

Comment: What do you mean _force it to use a specific method_? - you are calling the `_PartialGetMemo()` method

Comment: what i want is to know if my method was called by HttpPost or HttpGet..because i would like to add a filter on my controller [HttpPost] or [HttpGet]

Comment: If you want to always call a `[HttpGet] _PartialGetMemo()` method, then you just need to make sure that you do not also have a `[HttpPost]` method named `_PartialGetMemo`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke

Answer (score -1):

This Html.Action renders partial view as an HTML string so we can store it in another string variable. It is string return type method so first it returns result as a string then renders result to response.